# Sampling a jpg image at a grid of points

Tags: image-processing

I have a 1920x1440 jpg image. It has been binarized. I want to sample the values at an nxm grid of points say 50 points x 40 points. What is the most computationally efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If what you want is a smaller 50 x 40 version of the image, ImageResize[img, {50, 40}] would do.

Comment: ``img[[;; ;; 50, ;; ;; 40]]``

Comment: I don't want a 50x40 result - I want the (R,G,B) values of the image sampled at 50 points horizontally and 40 points vertically.  This is to be applied to every image in an image array from a video clip.  Then each point has a time series of RGB values associated with it.

Comment: Domen's answer should work, although you might need `ImageData[img][[;; ;; 50, ;; ;; 40]]`. This should give you back exactly what you need.

Comment: To sample at 50 points horizontally and 40 points vertically *does* give you a 50 x 40 result though, right? Do you mean you want to take a sample *every* 50 points horizontally and every 40 points vertically?

Comment: Also what do you mean by it having been binarized? To me, that means `Binarize` has been applied to it, but I think you must mean something different with it if you still have the RGB values hanging around.

Comment: Ummm...   why do you care about computational efficiency?   Everything is SOOO fast you can apply this to every image on your computer in less time it takes to post your question and get an answer.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Don't forget that Mathematica also runs (very very slowly) on Raspberry Pi. I'm not sure it would be pointless to think about computational efficiency in every case.

Comment: Processing tens of thousands of images on a Raspberry Pi?!?  That's what you'd need to see any *difference* in speed between the slowest and the fastest methods.  0.0015 versus 0.0017.  So 0.0002 seconds.  If you do 500 such calls, the *difference* is less than 1 second.  I ask again:  who gives a damn about efficiency here?  (Let's hear from the OP.)

Comment: I don't care about efficiency if the difference is that small - and yes at some point this might be run on an RPi4 with 4G RAM There are two different separate analyses to be done with this approach, one with R,G,B triple at each grid point, separately on a Binarized version of the image with 0/1  but the same grid sampling will be used in either case.  Hope this is not confusing.  Re ImgResize vs Downsample - not sure what ImgResize does to do its resizing but if I understand correctly Downsample does exactly what I want giving me a 50x40 subset of the values,  Thanks VERY MUCH, all!

Comment: Hmm, not quite—`Downsample[img, {n,k}]` will extract a pixel *every* `n` pixels horizontally and `k` pixels vertically. So for instance, if `img` is 10x10, `DownSample[img, {5,5}]` will give you a 2x2 image. Likewise `DownSample[img, {1,1}]` will give you back `img` instead of a 1x1 image. Is that what you want?

Comment: Perhaps the numbers I gave and what I wanted don't match in my statement of the problem and I can adjust the numbers to make it what I want. I do want an n x m grid so I would do `Downsample[1920/n, 1440/m]` - correct? The main questions I had were a) what function to use, and b) whether the efficiency would vary depending on the choice. Finding the actual {n,m} that will work for the analysis that follows, is part of a trial and error process, but I do get what you're saying. Thanks much again!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Let me put the efficiency requirement in perspective. On my machine—which isn't incredible, but also isn't too shabby (6 core 2.2 GHz intel, 16 GB RAM)—`ImageResize[#, {50,40}] & /@` on a list of 30 1920x1440 images takes about 1.2 seconds. 30 fps is typical for video. That means that the process of resizing a video like this would take about as long as it takes the video to play. For a video an hour long, that's a lot. However, including the option `Resampling -> "NearestLeft"` cuts the time more than in half. So, there is quite a bit of room for optimizing here, and it matters.

Comment: No no no.  `ImageResize` is *NOT* what you asked for:  "sample the values at an nxm grid."  Of course *resizing* an image is slow, but irrelevant to your stated problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I don't think I was confused about this part.  `ImageResize` was suggested as a solution but I was pretty clear it was not what I asked for as I wanted the actual values at the grid and wasn't looking for a resized image.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork `ImageResize` *does* sample pixels of the image though, and doesn't alter/average/process-together pixel values when either 1) `Resampling -> "NearestRight"|"NearestLeft"` or 2) the image is binarized, which OP said it was. Not sure how you think image resizing works, except by accessing (and in this case, sampling from) blocks of pixel values. So, it's not irrelevant to the stated problem. Note that the `Span` solution in the comments 1) doesn't get a 50 x 40 sample 2) the simple modification of it to do so results in edge artifacts. `ImageResize` takes care of that.

Comment: @thorimur:  I believe you are wrong for your explanation 2).  `xx = Image[Table[(1 + (-1)^(i + j))/2, {i, 100}, {j, 100}]]`, then `ImageResize[xx, 2]`, `ImageData[%]` yields:   {{0.500104, 0.499896}, {0.499896, 0.500104}} . Proof that `ImageResize` *DOES* "alter/average/process-together" a binarized image.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Check again—you didn't binarize the image. Use `xx = Binarize @ Image[Table[(1 + (-1)^(i + j))/2, {i, 100}, {j, 100}]]`. Then `ImageResize[xx, 2] // ImageData` is `{{1,1},{1,1}}`. Note that for your version of `xx`, `ImageType[xx]` is `"Real32"`. For the binarized version, it's `"Bit"`.

Comment: Oh... OK.  True binarize (in format), not merely two level.  Fair enough.  I've learned something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an `n`x`m` subset of pixels of a 1920x1440 image, you can try doing `Downsample[img, {Floor[1920/n], Floor[1440/m]}]`—but this doesn't guarantee an `n` x `m` grid will result, due to the floor function being used.

Let's assume you have a list of images `imgs` which are all known to be the same dimensions.

There are two ways: `ImageResize[#, {n, m}, Resampling -> "NearestLeft"] & /@ imgs`, or a custom function. If we go the custom function route, we can exploit the fact that we have the same dimensions for each image:

```
ImageSample[imgs_List, {x_Integer, y_Integer}] :=
 With[{img1 = First[imgs]},
  With[{i = ImageDimensions[img1], 
        type = ImageType[img1],
        info = Sequence @@ FilterRules[Normal@First@Information[img1], Options[Image]]}, 
   With[{xparts = Floor@Rescale[Range[x], {1, x}, {1, First[i]}], 
         yparts = Floor@Rescale[Range[y], {1, y}, {1, Last[i]}]}, 
    Image[#, type, info] & /@
     ((ImageData[#, type] & /@ imgs)[[All, yparts, xparts]])
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Note that this function is not "safe" and doesn't check that all image dimensions are the same (or even that the list is made of all images). If you want to do that, you can change `imgs_List` to `imgs : {___Image}` and append `/; Equal @@ (ImageDimensions /@ imgs)` to the definition.

This is guaranteed to get you an `x`x`y`-sized grid of pixels, if that's essential for you.

Surprisingly, this can be an order of magnitude faster than the built-in `ImageResize`, depending on the parameters `x`,`y`, if you really need it. It's best to time it yourself and see how it goes, though. The speed difference might also be negligible, depending on the dimensions and the number of frames. It can also be much slower sometimes, so watch out!

Note what we're doing with the ranges, as well: we're scaling them so that the first and last pixels of the sampling grid are right in the corners. You can fiddle with the last argument of `Rescale`, which tells you the range to rescale it *to*, if you want. You can also replace `Floor` with `Round` or `Ceiling`. Note that `ImageResize` chooses a slightly different convention: it apparently tries to sample from the center of rectangles that are `i[[1]]/x` wide by `i[[2]]/y` high. (Check out `ImageResize[Image[Array[{#1, #2, 0} &, {100, 100}], "Byte"], {5, 5}, Resampling -> "NearestLeft"]` to see it sampling from the middle of 20x20 squares). This could be replicated here with a small adjustment to the formula.

It also converts all the `ImageData` back to `Image`s. If you don't need that, and are happy with the array, simply remove `info = ...` and `Image[#, info] & /@`.

---

The above assumes you're trying to get exactly an `n`x`m` grid of points, and that being evenly spaced in "real" space is more important than being evenly spaced in pixel values. It also assumes you want to avoid sampling close to one edge but not the opposite one; one downside of using `Downsample` or simply `ImageData[img][[ ;; ;; m, ;; ;; n]]` is that you'll introduce edge artifacts or not get quite an `n` by `m` grid, but they are far faster. There are a couple of ways to modify them to be better:

To deal with edge artifacts:

1. Approximate solution: Calculate an appropriate offset for the sampling, so that the sampled pixels are approximately "centered"
2. More exact solution: Restrict the allowed downsampling spacing: for sampling right up to the edges, only use divisors of `(effective dimension) - 1`; for sampling in "pixel block centers", only use divisors of `(effective dimension)`. For this, we can crop our image dimensions slightly from `(dimension)` to `(effective dimension)`, which might have better divisors. (what if `(dimension)` is prime?)

There are also other ways we could sample the image: randomly, from a uniform distribution on locations; randomly within each pixel block; according to different rigid patterns; etc.

I'll come back to this to see if I have anything explicit to add! :)

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Yes, this is all very helpful and informational and will help a lot during the investigation.  The part about getting exactly n x m samples is also not very critical as what I am attempting to do is to get a sufficiently distributed set of samples from all over the image. However as I am new to Mathematica syntax all of this is helpful if/when I need to use these idioms, which is likely to be sooner rather than later..

Answer (score 0):

I think `Downsample[img, {50, 40}]` does it. Not sure if it's the most efficient.

Comment: That should be the most efficient! in general, built-ins win. contrast `ImageData[img][[;; ;; 40, ;; ;; 50]] // Image // RepeatedTiming` with `Downsample[img, {50, 40}] // RepeatedTiming`. (Note that image dimensions are in reverse order to their `ImageData` array dimensions, hence the flip of 40 and 50.)

Comment: Thanks, so much!

Comment: Weirdly enough, I'm trying it again now, and `Downsample` is losing?? I could've sworn when i tried it the first time it won! Maybe it did, with different parameters? The lesson, I guess, is to time it yourself with your parameters, and then use the best choice!

Comment: (Note that if you have a list of images `imgs` all of the same dimension, you can do `Image /@ (ImageData /@ imgs)[[All, ;; ;; 40, ;; ;; 50]]`.)